# Is it acceptable to use 'z' instead of 's' for plural form?

Tags: grammatical-number, american-english, british-english, writing-style

I am trying to find an appropriate name for my website but all domains are squattered. So now I think that I can call my site, say, not 'cats.com' by 'catz.com'. Isn't it too informal and 'leet' (or simply childish) spelling in US and British culture?

How often do you see this kind of writing in newspapers for example? I don't know how I should call my site — this naming seems a bit awkward for me and I think that people will say "hey one more school boy got the internet".

So please tell me about using of 'Z' instead of 'S' in modern culture.

Actually this is a website dedicated for applications developers. It think this is a kind of formal website, not funny or something like that. And the point is to call it "apps" or "appz". Name of this site going to appear in users custom pages, so the name should be as neutral as possible. From your answers I understand that "appz" is not a good idea.

Comment: If I saw *appz* written instead of *apps* I would think I was browsing a Warez website (now that I think about it: softwares -> softwarez).

Comment: It should be noted that one cannot obtain a trademark on a common word such as "parts", but one might possibly (if it hadn't already been claimed decades ago) obtain a trademark on "partz".

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The use of *z* instead of *s* is colloquial and informal.

Whether or not you want to use this form is up to you, but I think it depends very much on what kind of website you want: is it a personal or business website? What kind of products or services do you offer? What tone do you want your site to have?

If you're showing funny pictures of cats, then *catz.com* seems entirely appropriate. However, if you're selling worming products, then the more formal spelling might be better.

Without more information, it is difficult to answer this question.

Answer (score 5):

OK, I'll play the conservative: No, it's not appropriate and is never used in general (much less formal) writing. The only exception is when the writer wishes to communicate an ironic reference to net culture.

Comment: Why only an 'ironic' reference?

Comment: Or is that a satirical reference?

Comment: Since the use of a 'z' is such a pitiful way to gain net-cred, I would hope that its use would be ironic: "Check my l33t skillz!"

Answer (score 4):

That plural form is slangish and you wouldn't want to use it in some formal letter, for example.

About your site... Well, depends on the site itself.

If it's a **Portfolio**, so, something dedicated to your work and professional, then avoid it, absolutely. If it's a "random site", then it's up to you, according to what type of "mood" you want to assign to it.

Answer (score 2):

I'd be devil's advocate and say that it's nothing innately "wrong" or "informal" with using deliberate misspellings (such as "-z" for plural) in modern naming practice - at least it's clearly *does not* automatically makes you non-serious , anti-business or not-related-to-professional-work. There are lots of fairly serious businesses and organization that run "-z" names, for example:

- [MusicBrainz](http://musicbrainz.org/) and [MetaBrainz](http://metabrainz.org/) - one of the largest music encyclopedias and its controlling foundation
- [Starz Lacrosse Foundation](http://www.starzfoundation.org/) - a sport-promoting charity
- [Orbitz](http://www.orbitz.com/) - an online travel agency

Of course, there are also tons of companies that have "-z" as a result of having some non-American or British ancestry, such as Hertz, Andritz, Sojitz, [KGHM Polska Miedz](http://www.kghm.pl/), [Commerzbank](https://www.commerzbank.de/), Mondelēz, Immofinanz or [Aboitiz](http://aboitiz.com).